# Variables displayed incorrectly

Tags: arduino-uno, button, variables

I am making a keypad and when I try to save the buttons that were pushed they reset back to zero.

```
int tmp = 1;
int digit = 1;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
int code = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(7, INPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digit > 4) {
    digit = 1;
  }
  for (int i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
    int tmp = digitalRead(i);
    if (tmp == HIGH) {
      if (digit == 1) {
        int a = i - 1;
      }
      if (digit == 2) {
        int b = i - 1;
      }
      if (digit == 3) {
        int c = i - 1;
      }
      if (digit == 4) {
        int d = i - 1;
        Serial.print(a);
        Serial.print(b);
        Serial.print(c);
        Serial.print(d);
        digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
      }
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      delay(100);
      Serial.print(i);
      digit++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a library for a keypad: https://github.com/Chris--A/Keypad If you want to make your own code, you have to specify what you want: should multiple keys presses at the same time being detected ? should there be debouncing ? do you want to know how long a key is pressed ?

Comment: I already have key detection but for some reason when I have it output variables A B C and D it only stores the last digit and the rest are 0

Comment: @NathanAnderson - The compiler would be warning you about the issue, but warnings are turned off in the Arduino IDE by default.

Comment: You can make your code more flexible by keeping a running total (`int total = 0;`) and just add to it with each keypress: `total = (total * 10) + i;` - where `i` is the most recent digit input by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what `int a;` does?

For example you have a global variable `a` and then you have local `a`. Local one hides global one.

In all cases you're changing local variables. Then you're printing global `a`,`b`,`c` and local `d`.